# Histogram of most common words in collections.Counter object

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, nlp

I have a `collections.Counter` object called `word_counts`. The `len(word_counts)` is 88549. A sample of `print(word_counts)` output is

> `Counter({'said': 21179, 'trump': 18425, 'clinton': 14421, 'would': 12666, 'us': 12552, 'people': 11365, 'one': 11209, 'new': 9268, 'state': 8287, 'also': 8217, 'president': 8148, 'campaign': 7462, 'like': 7049, 'states': 6687, 'hillary': 6667, 'obama': 6572})`

I want to make a plot with the 5 most used words in the text with their number of occurrences.

I tried `plt.bar(word_counts.keys(), word_counts.values())` but it the code keeps running forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `N` most common words you may try:

```
from collections import Counter

words = ["this"]*100 + ["is"]*50 + ["an"]*30 + ["example"]*20 + ["of"]*10  + ["counter"]*5
word_counts = Counter(words)

N = 5
mc = word_counts.most_common(N)

plt.bar(*zip(*mc));
```

[image]

To better understand the meaning of `*zip(*mc)`, you may wish to pass it through print statement sequentially:

```
print(mc)
[('this', 100), ('is', 50), ('an', 30), ('example', 20), ('of', 10)]
```

---

```
print(*mc)
('this', 100) ('is', 50) ('an', 30) ('example', 20) ('of', 10)
```

---

```
print(list(zip(*mc)))
[('this', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'of'), (100, 50, 30, 20, 10)]
```

---

```
print(*zip(*mc))
('this', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'of') (100, 50, 30, 20, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it solves my problem. But I would like to know what does `zip` mean?  What do the asterisks in `zip` and `mc` do?

Comment: `mc`, which stands for most common, is a list of tuples. There are several ways to unpack the list of tuples into 2 iterables. I showed you one, where asterisk means unpacking. If you're not comfortable with this you may try `x = [i[0] for i in mc]; y = [i[1] for i in mc]; plt.bar(x,y)`

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. Your comment has been very helpful.